# Search IDictionary based on value member variable

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, steam-web-api

I've got an IDictionary with the KeyPair `<int, SteamApp>` where SteamApp is a custom class in the SteamAPI framework I'm using. The SteamApp class has a field `Name`, which I would like to search the dictionary by. I want to search for a specific game name. How do I do that?

Short code snippet:

```
foreach (var pair in allGames) {
            Debug.WriteLine(pair.Value.Name);
}
```

Comment: It would really help if you'd show a short but complete example rather than *describing* your code.

Comment: Why not use `Name` as your key then?

Comment: Also, what exactly is your data structure? You say you have an `IDictionary` with `KeyValuePair`? that sounds weird.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I simply use a function that returns the dictionary. I don't have control over the setup of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want all `KeyValuePair<int, SteamApp>` in the dictionary where the SteamApp-name is the same as you are searching?

```
var allKeyValues = dict.Where(kv => kv.Value.Name == searchedName);
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, SteamApp> kv in allKeyValues)
{
    // a game with that name exists in the dictionary
}
```

If you want to take only the first use `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var keyVal = dict.FirstOrDefault(kv => kv.Value.Name == searchedName);
if(keyVal.Value != null)
{
    // a game with that name exists in the dictionary
}
```

Comment: This was excatly what I was looking for! Thank you! I'm accepting the answer in 11 minutes.

Comment: KeyValuePair is not nullable, therefore you have to check if `kv.Value != null`

Comment: @Staeff: good point, i've forgotten that the `KeyValuePair` is a struct, hence a value type and therefore never null. He could also `Select(kv => new{ Key=kv.Key,Value=kv.Value })`. Then it was a class and he could use `if(keyVal!= null)`.